# Perdendo valores inseridos na lista após sair do método (C#)

Tags: c#, escopo-de-variáveis

Boa noite!

Iniciei meu aprendizado em C# há menos de 3 semanas e estou com problemas ao tentar manipular listas.
É uma aplicação em console bem simples.

Tenho um menu onde o usuário seleciona entre as opções de incluir, editar e excluir registros de livros na lista, e também a opção de imprimir a lista e limpar toda a lista. Cada funcionalidade possui um método responsável.

O problema é que, quando os registros da classe 'Livro' são incluídos no método Insert() e, ao voltar para o menu e chamar o método para imprimir a lista, não existe nenhuma saída, como se a lista estivesse vazia.

Se eu chamo o método para imprimir a lista dentro do próprio método de incluir os registros, todos os valores que eu cadastrei na lista são exibidos normalmente. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
                static  List <Book> Insert(){

                   List <Book>   bookList = new List<Book>();
                   Book books = new Book();

                   char reInsert;

                    do{

                    Console.Clear();

                    Console.WriteLine("Insira o titulo do livro: ");
                      
                      books.BookTitle=Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Insira o nome do autor: ");
                      books.AuthorName=Console.ReadLine();
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Insira a editora: ");
                        books.Publisher=Console.ReadLine(); 

                    Console.WriteLine("Insira o ano de lancamento: ");
                          books.ReleaseYear=Console.ReadLine();
               
                    Console.WriteLine("Insira o preco: ");
                          books.Price=decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Book book = new Book (books.BookTitle, books.AuthorName, books.Publisher, books.ReleaseYear, books.Price);

                    bookList.Add(book);

                    Console.WriteLine("Livro cadastrado com sucesso!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Deseja cadastrar outro livro? (S/N)");
                    reInsert=char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    } while(reInsert=='s');

                    return bookList;
                                   
            }
```

```
  static void Print( List<Book> bookList){
             
             Console.Clear();

             var books = bookList.OrderBy(p => p.BookTitle);
          
                foreach(var b in books){

                    Console.WriteLine(@$"Titulo da Obra: {b.BookTitle}
                                         Autor: {b.AuthorName}
                                         Editora: {b.Publisher}
                                         Ano: {b.ReleaseYear}
                                         Valor: {b.Price}\n");
                }
                        Console.ReadLine();
                                                
                }
           }
```

Chamando os métodos:

```
 static bool menu = true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  

            MainMenu();         
            
        }
         static void MainMenu(){
            
            do{
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t||eLib - v2.0||\n\n");

                Console.WriteLine("\t\tSelecione uma Opcao:\n");

                Console.WriteLine(@"
                
                1 - Cadastrar Livro

                2 - Editar Cadastro de Livro 

                3 - Remover um Livro

                4 - Limpar Base de Dados

                5 - Imprimir Livros Cadastrados

                6 - Sair
                
                "); 

                int index=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Options selectedOption = (Options)index;

                List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();

                
                switch(selectedOption){

                case(Options.Insert):

                bookList =  Insert();

                break;

                case(Options.Print):

                Print(bookList);

                  break;
```

Abraços.

Comment: Você está declarando a lista de livros dentro da função, então quando sair dela a lista não existirá mais. Tente declarar a lista fora da função

Comment: não @NatanFernandes, ele pode declarar dentro o método, mas ele faz return. Se ele entrar no método de Inserir e depois Print deveria funcionar. Thiago seu código só tem uns pedaços, não da pra ver como está declararando a variável `bookList` antes do `switch`, nem como está esse bloco, se fica num loop e se não declara novamente.... coloque o código completo para poder entender melhor

Comment: pelo seu código precisa declar a lista `bookList` antes do `do` principal do menu. Ai tem duas possibilidades, com o seu exemplo remover a criação da lista dentro do método `Insert`,  que vai apagar a lista, ou apenas passar o a lista para o método `Insert` como sugerido na resposta do @NatanFernandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note que está criando uma nova lista a cada vez que seleciona uma opção no loop. Para manter a lista desejada você deve declarar a lista de livros fora do laço de repetição.

```
List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
static void MainMenu(){
    do{
        ...
    }
}
```

Dentro da sua função `Insert`, você também cria uma nova lista. O correto, no meu ponto de vista seria passar a sua lista por parâmetro:

```
static void Insert(List<Book> bookList)
{
    Book books = new Book();

    ...

    bookList.Add(book);
}
```

Note que agora a função é do tipo `void` pois não vai retornar nada, só vai adicionar um livro à lista que foi passada.
A parte do switch ficaria assim:

```
switch (selectedOption)
{
    case(Options.Insert):
        Insert(livros);
        break;

    case(Options.Print):
        Print(livros);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Natan a lista pode ser perfeitamente devolvida pelo método insert, pode não ser esse o problema, sem ver todo o código, de como faz o loop e o tratamento da lista não dá pra responder com precisão. Imagina que esse seu código está dentro de um loop do menu, a cada ação do menu vai criar novamente a lista de livros e isso vai zerar do mesmo jeito, seu código não resolve o problema. Sim é possível passar a lista por parametro e declara fora do método como sugeriu, mas sem ver o loop do meu, esse código também vai falhar

Comment: Entendi, você acha melhor apagar a resposta ou esperar o autor dar alguma informação a mais?

Comment: Boa noite Ricardo e Natan, beleza? Obrigado pelo feedback. Correto, o método retorna a lista. De toda forma já havia tentado implementar da forma que o Natan explicou, mas também não deu certo. Ricardo, editei minha pergunta com a implementação do método MainMenu() onde chamo os métodos Insert() e Print()

Comment: Agora com o código todo acho que consegue perceber o problema e corrigr usa resposta @NatanFernandes

Comment: Obrigado pessoal. @NatanFernandes, deu certo. Precisei declarar a lista como static e deu tudo certo.

Comment: Obrigado @RicardoPontual pelo alerta!